# Telerik BusyIndicator does not Display

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, silverlight

I am using WCF Services

I have this problem:

When I retrieve data from server for my GridView at the start of an async function call, I set `IsBusy = "True"` . After the method is called, I set `IsBusy = "False"`. During the method call `RadBusyIndicator` does not Display. I cannot understand what the problem is.

I have uploaded a simple project with this problem. Can you check it? [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?pdd99yyju2b4rjp)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the loading in a BackgroundWorker, can you try this:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    //Activate BudyIndicator
    App.Instance.SetBusy();

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> LoadedCustomers = null;

        //Create Client
        proxy.ServicesClient client = new proxy.ServicesClient();
        ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = client.GetCustomers();

        LoadedCustomers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>();
        foreach (var item in customers)
        {
            LoadedCustomers.Add(new CustomerModel()
            {
                CustomerId = item.CustomerId,
                Title = item.Title,
                FirstName = item.FirstName,
                MiddleName = item.MiddleName,
                LastName = item.LastName,
                CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                SalesPerson = item.SalesPerson,
                EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
                Phone = item.Phone
            });
        }
        client.Close();

        //Define return value
        ea.Result = LoadedCustomers;
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
        //Get returned value
        ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> model = ea.Result as ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>;
        if (model != null)
        {
            Customers = model;
        }

        //Desactivate BusyIndicator
        App.Instance.UnSetBusy();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: I did it like you wrote but not works. At first it cames inside worker.RunWorkerCompleted {} and there ea.Result is null, after that it assigned in worker.DoWork {};
What is this BackgroundWorker class? threading???

Comment: The BackgroundWorker allows asynchronous processes. By filling its "ea.Result" property in DoWork, you can retrieve it in the calling thread in "RunWorkerCompleted".

Comment: but as I told you, it first come in worker.RunWorkerCompleted,  at this moment ea.Result is null, only after that worker.DoWork complets

Comment: This is the true BackgroundWorker itself launches an asynchronous process (GetCustomersAsync). Calling GetCustomers() in BackgroundWorker you can upload your data with BusyIndicator. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: First: It us not GetCustomers it is GetCustomersAsync. second:It has not return type, it is void. Can you download my project, make there corrections and send it me back?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see your problem. The Close method on your proxy wait the result of the asynch call.
Just move your client.Close(); in the GetCustomersCompleted method and this will work. (Tested with your sample)

```
private proxy.ServicesClient client = null;
private void LoadData()
{
    App.Instance.SetBusy();

    client = new proxy.ServicesClient();
    client.GetCustomersCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>();

            foreach (var item in e.Result)
            {
                Customers.Add(new CustomerModel()
                    {
                        CustomerId = item.CustomerId,
                        Title = item.Title,
                        FirstName = item.FirstName,
                        MiddleName = item.MiddleName,
                        LastName = item.LastName,
                        CompanyName = item.CompanyName,
                        SalesPerson = item.SalesPerson,
                        EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
                        Phone = item.Phone
                    });
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
        }
        client.Close();//Close after the return
        App.Instance.UnSetBusy();
    };
    client.GetCustomersAsync();
    //client.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Not works again :(, can you write in this project which I uploaded?? and send me it

Comment: I do not have to send the project repository. But it may be that the load is too fast .. To test I changed "Services.cs" to add a pause 5s as:

`public ObservableCollection <Customer> GetCustomers ()
{
Thread.Sleep (5000);
return new CustomerBLL (). GetCustomers ();
}`

Answer (score 0):

If your window xaml is not inside the busy indicator it may not show. With that control you need to put the content you wish to be masked when the busy indicator is set to true inside the indicator tags. If you UserControl's primary display item is a Grid then wrap the grid in the busy indicator tags.

```
<UserControl>
  <telerik:RadBusyIndicator IsBusy={Binding Busy}>
      <Grid>
         content...
      </Grid>
   </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
</UserControl>
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I did it, but not works again. Well, I did experiment, remove line where I set Is IsBusy = "false", in GetCustomersCompleted event, and notice when data is loaded, after that Displays BusyIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a binding for the IsBusy property on the controller, which I assume you are, then you must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface so that when the value of the binding property is changed the UI is notified of that change and updates itself. 
Your view model should have  a property with a setter as follows:

```
    public bool Busy
    {
        get{return _Busy;}
        set
        {
           if(value != _Busy)
             _Busy = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Busy");
        }

    }
```

This will notify the UI of the change;
If you are doing this already then I will need to see more of the relevant code to help more.

After I looked at your last post again if you are setting the IsBusy property to a string value that is your problem as that property takes a Boolean value.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?pdd99yyju2b4rjp here I uploaded this simple project, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume based on your code you wish to only put the busy indicator over the content control on the main window. My recommendation is to create a view model for the main window and use it as the datacontext for the page. I would also set up a property on the view model as explained above and set up a binding to that property. In the view model you can make the async call to the data store and on the return fill a collection property (recommend ObservableCollection) and bind your ListBox's IitemsSource property to that.
I hope this helpls